# Uniformity of Analytic Function Growth Order

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

Let function $f(z),\,z=re^{i\theta}\in\mathbb C$ for $r,\theta\in\mathbb R$ on the complex plane $\mathbb C$, be analytic in the interior and continuous on the whole closed domain of the wedge $|\theta|\le \frac{\pi}{2\alpha},\,\alpha>1$.

1. Does
   $$\limsup_{r\to\infty}\frac{\ln\ln(f(re^{i\theta}))}{\ln r}=\rho \tag{1}$$
   for some postive $\rho$ 
   point-wise in $\theta$ implies uniformly in $\theta$?
2. Suppose Equation (1) holds

2.a point-wise;

2.b uniformly,

does 
$$\limsup_{r\to\infty}\frac{\ln(f(re^{i\theta}))}{r^\rho}=\tau \tag{2}$$
for some $\tau\in\mathbb R$ point-wise in $\theta$ imply uniformly in $\theta$?

Comment: the maximum/minimum modulus principle might be useful ?

Comment: @user1952009: But how do we apply that? In the case of pointwise convergence, the radius of the boundary for a constant bound of $f$ could be $\theta$ dependent and therefore nonuniform with respect to $\theta$, if your intention is to establish the uniformity.